# Is include() cached with fastcgi?

Tags: php, cache, fastcgi, javascript

I have a script like this

**script.php**

```
<?php
include "data/package.php";
echo $package[0]["name"];
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

and i do cache false with this

```
map $request_uri $cache_false {
    default 0;
    ~^/data/package.php?$ 1;
    ~^/signin.php?$ 1;
}
...
fastcgi_cache cache
fastcgi_cache_bypass $cache_false;
fastcgi_no_cache $cache_false;
```

and `package.php` use the session from `signin.php` page

****signin.php****

```
$_SESSION['package'] = 1;
```

****package.php****

```
$package = packages($_SESSION['package']);
```

---

I wanna cache the `script.php` while having the `$package` content change without getting cached because every user is different in his `packages()`.

Does setting `$cache_false = 1` for `signin` and `package` pages make `include()` content changed?

Do I only need to use javascript and add the content from the client only?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx caches the full response of a URL. If you request `https://www.example.com/script.php`, nginx will pass the request to PHP-FPM which executes the script first time when accessing the URL.

nginx returns the cached content for subsequent requests.

So, if there is an `include` in `script.php`, it is executed the first time, and then it is not executed anymore, because `script.php` output is already in cache.